# android screen i scrolling down on every input to editText insert

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_bg" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


....
                <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_verificationcode" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.0" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/inputBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
                            style="@style/textOnBg"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:hint="-  -  -  -  -"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:textColor="#516063"
                            android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
                            android:textSize="25dp" >
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7" />

          ...

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the following code

which suppose to detect softkeboard opening and scroll the view a bit down (once)

```
    public class PhoneVerifyYourNumbersActivity extends Activity {

        private String mDisplayOptions[] = new String[3];
        private LinearLayout mInputBox;
        private LinearLayout mContinueButton;
        private TextView mVerifyByPhoneCallText;

        private ScrollView mScrollView;

        private EditText mVerificationCodeEditText;
        private String mHash = null;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.phone_verify_your_numbers);

            mHash = getIntent().getStringExtra("Hash");

            initMembers();
            setOnClickListeners();
            initFieldsTexts();
            setKeyboardVisibilityListener();

        }

..

        private void setKeyboardVisibilityListener() {
            final View root = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

            root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            int heightDiff = root.getRootView().getHeight()
                                    - root.getHeight();
                            if (heightDiff > 100) { // more than 100 pixels is
                                                    // probably a keyboard
                                // keyboard is shown
                                mInputBox
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_box_active);
                                //mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
                                mScrollView.scrollBy(0, +20);
                            } else {
                                // keyboard is not shown
                                mInputBox
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_box_idle);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
}

}
```

my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".phone.PhoneVerifyYourNumbersActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

a strange behavior is that whenever the user insert input to the editText,

the scroll moves 1-2 dps down wise. What can cause this?

I guess this `mScrollView.scrollBy(0, +20);` happens multiple times

but then how can I make it happen once?

(any clever idea other than adding a boolean flag `isMovedAlready`) ?

Answer (score 0):

`mScrollView.scrollBy()` is scrolling by `px`(Pixels) not `dp`. you may want to calculate dp to px first.
but i think you want something different. something like this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.verificationCodeEditText);
mScrollView.scrollTo(0, v.getBottom()+10);//or similar
```

Comment: but isn't this `onGlobalLayout` called only once after the keyboard is out? not on every input insert to the editText?

Comment: i am not sure about this. especially not for all android versions. but it can also be called by other reasons. `Callback method to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes` so nearly every view/view layout changing action could cause a call.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try to add one properties on AndroidManifest.xml Activity declaration like below.
**AndroidManifest.xml** 
<activity
  android:name="PhoneVerifyYourNumbersActivity"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Comment: i have added my current manifest. isn't this `onGlobalLayout` called only once after the keyboard is out? not on every input insert to the editText?